# Page crash when redirect to Mailchimp OAuth login page

Tags: javascript

When my application redirect to Mailchimp login page for allowing OAuth permission, we are getting permission error in javascript in Mailchimp OAuth Login window. the following are the error shown

"DOMException: Failed to execute 'query' on 'Permissions': Push Permission without userVisibleOnly:true isn't supported yet."

"Failed to execute 'query' on 'Permissions': Failed to read the 'name' property from 'PermissionDescriptor': The provided value 'speaker' is not a valid enum value of type PermissionName."

Is the above error significant enough to crash the page? Why are these errors are coming? Even after updating my browsers to the latest version, still the error occurs.

Regards,
Lokesh

I tried in latest version of all browsers and the issue still persists